# Migrate from joomla 3.4 to drupal 8.x

Tags: migrations

We are trying to migrate website from joomla 3.4 to drupal 8. We followed this [Tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process/migrate-process-overview) , but could not able to succeed in migration. And came to know that Drupal default migrate module will only support drupal 6, 7 to drupal 8.

Comment: welcome to drupal world Sravani, and congrats to this good decision, I did it 8 years ago ;) . at this time there is not a module to port joomla 3.4 to drupal, and according to https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview you should write a migration for it ( don't afraid it is not hard to a developer)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This is a site for narrowly scoped, detailed questions about Drupal...currently this is just a few statements without any question, so it's not possible to provide an answer. Please note that providing a tutorial to Migrate an unrelated framework to Drupal is beyond what our format supports, but if you have a _specific_ question about part of the process from a Drupal point of view, ask a separate question with all the required information in it. Many thanks